# PHPSTORM: Show TODO comments in all open files

Tags: phpstorm, todo

How can I see all my TODO comments in all the open files in PhpStorm?

I cannot find this option in the Scope Based tab, nor I can define this view by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot -- there is no such scope.

Unless, of course, if you create some custom scope and *manually* add all opened files there (which is not the way to go ... as you would need to *manually* update such scope when you open new/close old files).

Feel free to **submit Feature Request** to the Issue Tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI